# organize sql server enterprise manager DB Diagram view

Tags: sql-server, ssms

As i get more and more tables, using the diagram view becomes harder and harder.  is there anyway to have it auto order or sort to align joined tables, etc and avoid having to do it manually

Comment: What version of SQL Server/Management Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the diagram view, right click on an empty white space and click arrange tables.

[alt text http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/3193/71022491.png](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/3193/71022491.png)

Answer (score 2):

As you get more and more tables, attempting to have a single diagram that shows your entire database becomes almost pointless. We've got multiple diagrams that show functional areas of our application(s). Such as Work in Process, Process History, Security etc. This is much more useful to us.

Randy